# Define random default value in class-validator for each request in NestJS

Tags: node.js, validation, nestjs, default-value, class-validator

How can I specify a field to have a default value for each request? not for all requests. I know how can I pass the default value for a field in the class-validator:

```js
export class CreateUserDto {
  @IsString()
  username = "static-username";
}
```

But this piece of code would cause a static default value for all requests, But I need to generate a username for each request. Note: I know I can handle these kinds of problems/issues in the controller. but I think it is better to handle it in the validator. in the following example, you can see what i mean by handling the random value in the controller:

```js
class CreateUserDto {
  @IsOptional()
  @IsString()
  username?: string;
}

/* ... */
@Post('/users')
async createUser(@Body user: CreateUserDto) {
  if (user.username === undefined) {
    user.username = `random-${Math.random()}`
  }
}
/* ... */
```

Comment: maybe this will help you: https://github.com/typestack/class-validator/issues/177#issuecomment-474871305

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not true that you can only send back static values in the DTO. You can simply do this:

```js
class CreateUserDto {
  @IsOptional()
  @IsString()
  username: string = `random-${Math.random()}`
}

/* ... */
@Post('/users')
async createUser(@Body(new ValidationPipe({ whitelist: true })) user: CreateUserDto) {
  console.log(user.username) // random-0.8392092045730202
}
/* ... */
```

Maybe your issue while testing was that you are not enabling the ValidationPipe: `@Body user: CreateUserDto` has to be `@Body(ValidationPipe) user: CreateUserDto`. With `whitelist: true` you will also remove all not defined key value pairs which is quite helpful.

Comment: Yes, I did not attend that DTOs should be run for each incoming request once. Now Its system becomes more clear.

Comment: Does this validation pipe overrides global validation pipe?

Comment: @AliSherafat Yes, when you write one globally it will get used everywhere. When you write one in your function it will override the global one.